# Generate a warning/error when TypeScript infers 'any' as return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

Is there a way I can configure TypeScript to generate a warning/error when it infers `any` as the return type of a function?  If it infers `number` or something it's not so bad, but `any` opts out of type checking and has tripped me up several times, yet I have to remember to check every function to make sure it's not returning `any`.  I'd like this to be flagged up to me.

As an example of code that would cause this to be flagged up, ideally:

```
export default class MyClass {
    // ...

    #myMethod = (e: any) => {
        return e && e.target && e.target.hasName("stage");
    };

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Did you enable `noImplicitAny`?

Comment: Yes.  The following doesn't warn me.  I know I'm opting into `any` by giving it as the type of the `e` param, but I'd still like TS to warn me about the inferred return value: `myMethod = (e: any) => { return e && e.target && e.target.hasName("stage"); };`

Comment: Please consider including in the question a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue, and only your issue, when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.   Looks like your comment is close (maybe just needs a `const` before it?).  Presumably you are also looking for possibilities with linters?  TypeScript itself doesn't give this to you, and I'm not sure if something like eslint is in scope or out of scope for the question.

Comment: For example, it's possible that someone who knows about `typescript-eslint` would tell you how to write your own custom rule that does this for you, but in that case you might want to tag the question for that

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: if you are using ts eslint, check/configure `explicit-function-return-type` rule [https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md].

Comment: That doesn't quite seem to do what I want, as it requires all functions to have a return type, not just those that are inferred to be `any`.

Comment: Well uh, [here's](https://tsplay.dev/mAQk8m) a very limited TypeScript-only solution that only works for public members and cannot provide a helpful error message for fields... Also it can't differ between implicit `any` and explicit `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return` lint rule
https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-return

[typescript-eslint playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play#ts=4.8.4&sourceType=module&code=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAsgJ4DC+RcA3gFBxwD0zcAdJ-Y3AMQC2ZEsBgALCAjgBeOAApgALjioAdmQCU0gHx0eTKCPRQVcYHABk50+xiooAcxEWrwG3ccx2owgDlU-YFkAIgJbRyD1AG4eAF9onlYOLhigA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1tieQEMAZolrRE+WNCbooiaNA7RI4MAF8QKoA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)

Note that this lint rule requires [type-aware linting](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/typed-linting)

Comment: Is there an equivalent `no-unsafe-assign` or something, whereby you get a warning whenever a variable is assigned an `any`?  I've just had a nasty bug that existed because I was getting back an `any` from an external library, which opted a bunch of code out of type checking.  The ease with which TS can quietly opt out is really annoying!

Comment: @Jez yes, there are a few variants for different cases. You can find all the rules listed here https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/